# Azure webjob logging is slow

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

I have a continuous running webjob that pulls message from a service bus queue, processes them, and persists data to a SQL database.  The processing can sometimes be database intensive.

In trying to increase the performance of the webjob, I noticed one of the largest bottlenecks seems to be logging. I have logging enabled to blob storage and set the level to informational. When I turn off logging (via the portal) the message processing rate triples!  Re-enabling the logging brings the performance back down.

Are there any tricks to get the logging performance up?  I have checked the obvious things like setting up the storage account in the same location and resource group.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that some improvements were made in WebJobs 2.0, which is still in pre-release (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/2.0.0-beta1). Can you give that a shot to see if that helps?